# adding static attribute to constructor attribute

Tags: java, static

The problem is the following:

> (Savings Account Class) Create class SavingsAccount. Use a static
>   variable annualInterestRate to store the annual interest rate for all
>   account holders. Each object of the class contains a private instance
>   variable savingsBalance indicating the amount the saver currently has
>   on deposit. Provide method calculateMonthlyInterest to calculate the
>   monthly interest by multiplying the savingsBalance by
>   annualInterestRate divided by 12—this interest should be added to
>   savings- Balance. Provide a static method modifyInterestRate that sets
>   the annualInterestRate to a new value. Write a program to test class
>   SavingsAccount. Instantiate two savingsAccount objects, saver1 and
>   saver2, with balances of $2000.00 and $3000.00, respectively. Set
>   annualInterestRate to 4%, then calculate the monthly interest for each
>   of 12 months and print the new balances for both savers. Next, set the
>   annualInterestRate to 5%, calculate the next month’s interest and
>   print the new balances for both savers.

I solved it all, but the balance is not incrementing -- it is staying the same. It should increment with every change in annual interest rate (at least, that's what I understood).

```
class SavingsAccount
{
    static double annualInterestRate;
    private double savingsBalance;

    public SavingsAccount(double balance)
    {
        savingsBalance = balance;
    }

    public double calculateMonthlyInterest()
    {
        return (savingsBalance*annualInterestRate)/12;
    }

    public static void modifyInterestRate(double rate)
    {
        annualInterestRate = rate;
    }


    public static double getannualInterestRate(){return annualInterestRate;}

    public double getsavingsBalance(){return savingsBalance;}

}

public class SavingsTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SavingsAccount saver1 = new SavingsAccount(2000.0);
        SavingsAccount saver2 = new SavingsAccount(3000.0);

        SavingsAccount.modifyInterestRate(4);

        System.out.printf("Balance for Saver1 = %.2f\nBalance for Saver2 = %.2f\nInterest Rate = %.2f\n\n",saver1.getsavingsBalance()+saver1.calculateMonthlyInterest(),saver2.getsavingsBalance(),SavingsAccount.getannualInterestRate());

        SavingsAccount.modifyInterestRate(5);

        System.out.printf("New Balance for Saver1 = %.2f\nNew Balance for Saver2 = %.2f\nInterest Rate = %.2f\n\n",saver1.getsavingsBalance(),saver2.getsavingsBalance(),SavingsAccount.getannualInterestRate());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that changing the interest rate should change the account balance. If this is your only problem, I think this is working correctly

Comment: none of your code actually modifies the `savingBalance` variable (with the exception of the constructor). You have to actually change the value somewhere, I don't know where you want to do that.

Comment: BTW your formatting / naming conventions are not good. Assuming this is hw, you may lose points for style

Comment: Please fix the title, at the very least. I am *sure* that is not the terminology used by the instructor!

Answer (score 1):

You are not modifying the value of `savingsBalance` in this code.

Comment: shouldnt balance change when i do this?                       public SavingsAccount(double balance)
{
savingsBalance = balance+calculateMonthlyInterest();
}

Answer (score 0):

```
public double addMonthlyInterest()     {    
  savingsBalance += (savingsBalance*annualInterestRate)/12;
  return savingBalance;     
}
```

This will return the new balance and 'increment'

Answer (score 0):

In your first print statement, for the first argument you are calculating the balance after calculating the monthly interest and adding them together and didn't set the new value as the value of the class member savingsBalance.

In your second print statement, since you did not set the calculated value back to the class member through a setter, it is simply printing out the original value that the classes were instantiated with.

On a side note, don't do inline calculations in print statements. They are confusing and not easy to read for anyone. A good way is to initialize local members in the method and using them for calculations and printing the local members.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share my answer.

public class SavingsAccount {

```
private static float annualInterestRate = 0f;
private float savingsBalance;

public SavingsAccount(float balance) {
    savingsBalance = balance;
}

public static void setAnnualInterestRate(float t) {
    if (t >= 0 && t <= 1)
        annualInterestRate = t;
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Annual interest rate should be between 0 and 1");
}

private float calculateMonthlyInterest() {
    return savingsBalance * annualInterestRate / 12;
}

public float getSavingsBalance() {
    return savingsBalance + calculateMonthlyInterest();
}

public float getAnnualInterestRate(){
    return annualInterestRate;
}

public String toString() {
    return String.format("Balance: %.2f", getSavingsBalance());
}
```

}

in main

```
    SavingsAccount s1 = new SavingsAccount(2000);
    SavingsAccount s2 = new SavingsAccount(3000);
    SavingsAccount.setAnnualInterestRate(0.04f);

    System.out.println("S1: " + s1);
    System.out.println("S2: " + s2);

    SavingsAccount.setAnnualInterestRate(0.05f);
    System.out.println("S1: " + s1);
    System.out.println("S2: " + s2);
```